# putting custom status bar

Tags: iphone, ipad

[image]

Hello,
 I want to put custom status bar in notification window of iphone. is it possible
 Will Apple allow this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put a widget in the Notification Center like the Weather widget...

Currently, Apple doesn't provide an API for that. You only can post [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) to display there (if the user configured in that way).